# VBA Copy list of years in column up to keyword

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently trying to create a feedback sheet on Excel, I am completely new to VBA.

I have a column populated with years (2014...2015 etc..) starting in cell A4 (sheet 1) continuing until the cell containing "Grand Total"

I would like copy all of the years up to the "Grand Total" cell in this column to sheet 2, bearing in mind that the year values and row locations are constantly changing...I would also like the new list on sheet 2 to not include the empty rows that are present between the years on sheet 1.

Any tips?

Cheers, 
Matt

Comment: Welcome to SO. You will receive *a lot* more help if you read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question with your coding efforts and let us know where it is failing.

Comment: As @ScottHoltzman says please read the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Provide screenshots of you data and how you try to acomplish your job, and we will help you.

Comment: Cheers @ScottHoltzman and ElbertV,  will do - Matt

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Sub getInfo()
Dim counter As Integer, lastRow As Integer
counter = 1
lastRow = Cells.Find(What:="Grand Total", After:=[A4], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For i = 4 To lastRow
    If Cells(counter, 1).Value < lastRow Then
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next i

Range("A4:A" & counter + 1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Columns(1)
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
For i = 1 To lastRow
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then
        Cells(i, 1).Delete
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```